# How do I fix DNS when connecting to a vpn using VPNC Front End for Windows

Tags: vpnc

When connecting to a VPN using [VPNC Front End](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vpncfe/) for Windows 8, web browsers fail to resolve DNS addresses. I can use nslookup from the terminal, and entering the IP addresses directly into the browser works, so there is a valid connection.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trick didn't work under Windows 8.1. Instead I had to following the instructions found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311218.

```
Click Start, click Run, type regedit32 in the Open box, and then click OK.
Click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage
In the right pane, double-click Bind.
In the Value data box, select the "\Device\NdisWanIp" item, press CTRL+X, click the top of the list of devices, and then press CTRL+V.
Click OK, and then quit Registry Editor.
```

The device GUID for the VPN adapter on my system was `\Device\{072F5025-EBEB-4408-BE1C-1E015F4838FD}` (I only found that by trail an error). When I put that at the top of the list, my DNS queries worked once the VPN cpnnection was established.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing the solution here because this drove me nuts for months.

The solution to this is to have a script that runs the following commands:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /flushdns
```

This script can be run after a VPN connection is established by adding it as a Post-Script.

[image]